# $scope.isAuthenticated returns false after refresh page

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I'm managing authentication with JWT. I'm trying to use ng-show to show/hide login and logout buttons in my nav. It's work fine , but after i refresh my page it's look like i'm not login anymore, the variable $scope.isAuthenticated returns false after refreshing, how can i keep $scope.isAuthenticated true as long i'm login ??

app.js

```
myApp.controller('UserCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $window) {
  $scope.user = {username: '', password: ''};
  $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
  $scope.welcome = '';
  $scope.message = '';

  $scope.submit = function () {
    $http
      .post('/authenticate', $scope.user)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
        $scope.isAuthenticated = true;
        var encodedProfile = data.token.split('.')[1];
        var profile = JSON.parse(url_base64_decode(encodedProfile));
        $scope.welcome = 'Welcome ' + profile.first_name ;
        $scope.error = '';
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

        delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
       $scope.error = 'Error: Invalid user or password';
        $scope.welcome = '';
      });
  };

  $scope.logout = function () {
    $scope.welcome = '';
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.isAuthenticated = false;
    delete $window.sessionStorage.token;
  };

});
```

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
      <span  ng-show="isAuthenticated">{{welcome}}</span>
      <form ng-show="!isAuthenticated" ng-submit="submit()">
        <input ng-model="user.username" type="text" name="user" placeholder="Username" />
        <input ng-model="user.password" type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
        <input  type="submit" value="Login" />

      </form>

      <div ng-if="error" class="alert alert-danger"> {{error}}</div>
      <div ng-show="isAuthenticated">
        <a ng-click="callRestricted()" href="">Shh, this is private!</a>
        <br>
        <div>{{message}}</div>
        <a ng-click="logout()" href="">Logout</a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You would need to save the "authenticated" state somehow (local storage, cookie, etc) and read it on first load (your main module's `run` block is a good place to do so)

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there's a token in local storage and set value of "isAuthenticated" accordingly using a service:

```
$scope.isAuthenticated = AuthService.isAuthenticated();
```

AuthService would then be responsible for checking if there's a token in the local storage.